# jQuery Form, ASP.NET MVC JSon Result

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to return a json result from a jQuery Form instance - but it keeps prompting me to download a file instead of displaying it in the window like it is supposed to...

```
    $("#ajaxImageForm").ajaxForm({
        iframe: true,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            $("#ajaxImageForm").block({ message: '<img src="/content/images/loader.gif" /> Uploading . . .' });
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $("#ajaxImageForm").unblock();
            $.growlUI(null, result.message);
        }
    });

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult Edit(FormCollection collection)
    {
        // return Json to the jQuery Form Result
        return new JsonResult {  Data = new { message = string.Format("edited successfully.") } };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are requesting a `GET` from your jQuery code, but you are stating that the action is only for `POST`.  Change one of those and you should be good.

```
$("#ajaxImageForm").ajaxForm({
    iframe: true,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        $("#ajaxImageForm").block({ message: '<img src="/content/images/loader.gif" /> Uploading . . .' });
    },
    success: function(result) {
        $("#ajaxImageForm").unblock();
        $.growlUI(null, result.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Nope. I still just get it presented as a downloadable file.

Comment: it could be something to do with ajaxForm.  Have you just tried a standard jQuery ajax?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to do it with a standard jQuery ajax.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax you seem to be using a ton of jQuery plugins which may be the problem

Comment: Thank you very much - the error is because it was flagged to use the iFrame. This in turn was causing it not to be returned to the right window.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the ajax request type to "GET", but your action method is set to only accept requests of type POST.

Try changing it to POST instead.

Comment: The method itself works - any code I place in there runs. It's the return that doesn't work. It DOES work ,it just presents it as a Downloadable file - instead of jQuery accepting it like it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar issue, although not sure the reasoning was the same.  The way I found to fix this was to return a content result instead with the content type set to text/html.

i.e.

```
return Content("{message: 'edited successfully'}", "text/html");
```